# Remove one of multiple background images using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background, background-image

when using multiple layered backgrounds in css3, how can I peel away the layers using jquery on click events?

```
body {
background:url(./images/bg2.jpg), url(./images/bg1.jpg);
}
```

so in this case one background will show up on top of another. I want to use jquery to just remove the top background. any ideas?

Comment: $("body").css("background","url(./images/bg2.jpg)");  should work

Comment: @user733421, that's rather specific. Not sure if OP knows the URL of the image layers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove the first background:

```
var bg = $("body").css("background");
var bgs = bg.split(',');
bgs.splice(0,1);
$("body").css("background", bgs.concat());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var currentsBodyBg = $('body').css('background');
    // DELETE every backgrounds after the first;
    var new =currentsBodyBg.replace(/,.*/gi, ";"); 
    $('body').css('background', new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var b = $('body');
    var images = b.css('background-image').split(',');
    b.css('background-image', images[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `background-image` instead of `background`, otherwise the returned string contains `no-repeat top left scroll transparent` ore something else too.

The topmost background-image is the `first` in the comma-separated list of urls. Splitting the string at each `,` gives an array of all urls. `slice(1)` returns an array with all items after the first.

`join(',')` converts that array back to a string with `,` between the items.

```
var $body = $("body");
var imgs = $body.css("background-image").split(',');
$body.css("background-image", imgs.slice(1).join(','));
```

You can have that as an oneliner, but with one disadvantage: `$("body")` is created two times:

```
$("body").css({backgroundImage: $("body").css("backgroundImage").split(',').slice(1).join(',')});
```